# Whats the best way to write test for testing Routes?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, routes

I wanted to write a test for main.tsx. Below is the code for the same. I haven't written any test for routes before. How do I write test for these routes?

```
const init = async () => {
  const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: `${HISTORY_BASENAME}` });

  // Catch link clicks and push them to the history object.
  handleNavigation(history);
  const renderCreateOldSliModal = () => <OldSliCreateModal />;
  const renderCreateSRModal = (forceProblemType?: SupportType) => (
    <CreateSRModal forceProblemType={forceProblemType} interPluginContext= 
      {pluginListener.getContext()} />
  );
  
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Configuration value={{ language: startData.initialContext.locale }}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <NavMenuContextProvider navigation={navTree}>
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  path={`/${ResourceNames.serviceRequest}/${ResourceNames.create}`}
                  render={renderCreateOldSliModal}
                />
                <Route
                  path={`/${ResourceNames.create}`}
                  render={() => renderCreateSRModal()}
                  exact={true}
                />
            </Switch>
         </NavMenuContextProvider>
       </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    </Configuration>,
    document.getElementById(CONTAINER_ID)
};
init();
```

I wrote a test like below, but I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
```

Below is my test

```
it("check routes", () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    const { container } = render(
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <NavMenuContextProvider navigation={undefined}>
          <Switch>
            <Route history={history}>
              path="/support/create"
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </NavMenuContextProvider>
      </ConnectedRouter>,
    );
    expect(container.innerHTML).toMatch("Open a Support Request");
  });
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined``` , this error was happening because I was not importing react properly. I fixed that. Now I get a different error. 
```React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.```

Answer (score 0):

I did the below way and I was able to successfully run the test

```
it("check routes for support create page", () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    const pluginListener = new SupportPluginListener();
    history.push("/support/home");
    const { getByText, debug } = render(
      <Provider store={mockConnectorStore}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Home/>
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
    );
    const titleText = getByText(/Open a Support Request/);
    expect(titleText).toBeDefined();
  });
```